# Migration angularjs project to reactjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, dependency-injection

I have searched through several examples and many articles for migration of angularjs projects to reactjs. But till now I have only found the lowest level of migration i.e. implementation of directives in reactjs. What I need to know is it is easy to rewrite code for controllers and routing as well? And what about dependency injection?

Comment: If you know both well it's easy. If you don't you'll have to learn. There's no magic way to do it.

Comment: angular's philosophy for app design is **radically** different from react's philosophy.  You may as well be asking about the best way to migrate a Java project to C#;  Even though the code looks similar, and many concepts are the same, it's still going to take rewriting a significant amount of the time.

Comment: https://tech.small-improvements.com/2017/01/25/how-to-migrate-an-angularjs-1-app-to-react/

There was an article explaining how to do the migration. But in the chapter 1, they have not described the way of migrating complex parts. And I could not find a chapter 2.

Comment: It will be easy to migrate to Vue.js. As it has benefit from both angular and react. Plus it is very good documented for quick learning.